# Servo MG996R - what is the maximum load for very long time?

Tags: servo

I am working on a device which will have to periodically switch positions and keep the position for very long time, as accurate as possible, under tension.

Never worked with servo motors before, but I found MG996R interesting. It has a stall torque of approx 12kg*cm (@6V).

**My question is:**

To what maximum safe continuous load I could subject the motor if I need to keep it in position for 24h+ (it may switch position occasionally, but worst scenario would be like 24h-48h continuous locking in same position) ?

Comment: perhaps you could use a brake of some type ... release the brake to move to another position, then re-apply the brake

Comment: i'm trying to limit the weight, but thank you for the suggestion! Another option was a latch mechanism, to lock in place once position has been changed, but I am still interested to figure out how much stress a servo motor would take considering my requirements.

Comment: There is by far not enough information to answer your question. The force that acts on the motor axis depends on the rotation angle. the length of the lever the direction of the "tension" force vector. The time the motor can withstand a force depends on it's stall torque, the current through the motor on high load and the time the motor is allow to be driven with this current. It also depends on the  current through the driver and the time the driver can handle this. There is also a rot angle where the torsion force to the motor is minimal (near 0), so it dep. on the mech. robustn. o.t. motor.